# How to combine two syntax highlightings in one syntax file for sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, text-editor

I want to be able to syntax highlight files like Vue.js where javascript and css appear in the same file like so:

```
// Some JavaScript code
function hello() {
    console.log("Hello");
}

====
.selector {
    color: red;
}
----

let foo = 'bar'

====
.foo {
    bar : 'baz';
}
----
```

I presumed, that there is a way to conditionally switch between two syntax highlightings in Sublime YAML files. I tried various things...

```
%YAML 1.2
---
name: Test
file_extensions: [test]
scope: source.test
extends: Packages/User/JavaScript.sublime-syntax
version: 2

contexts:
  main:
    - include: 'scope:source.js'
    - match: '===='
      push: 'css-block'

  css-block:
    - match: '----'
    - include: 'scope:source.css'
      pop: true
      # embed: scope:source.css
      # escape: '----'
```

After hours of reading docs and chatting with gpt, I am non the wiser :( Anybody knows the secret recipe?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems with your current approach.

- in the `main` context, you are overriding everything, meaning no default rules from the `JavaScript.sublime-syntax` file's `main` context are evaluated. This can be fixed with `meta_prepend: true` to ensure your rules come first. This will prevent the need to `- include: 'scope:source.js'`.
- the `main` context of the JavaScript syntax definition just checks for a shebang and then switches to the `script` context. Which in turn, basically just includes the `statements` context. **This** is where you want to put a match pattern for `====`.
- rather than pushing a `css-block` context which includes the CSS syntax, it is better to use `embed`/`escape`, otherwise if the CSS syntax pushes into another context internally, it will no longer evaluate the match patterns from your `css-block` context.
- having `pop: true` on an `include` will have no effect. `pop` only applies to `match` directives.

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
name: Test JS
file_extensions: [test]
scope: source.test
extends: Packages/JavaScript/JavaScript.sublime-syntax
version: 2

contexts:
  statements:
    - meta_prepend: true
    - match: '===='
      embed: scope:source.css
      escape: '----'
```